# PHP Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

I keep getting this error ***PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context*** and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.  Is there another set of eyes that can help?  I have  another class set up similarly and that one isn't throwing errors.  code is as follows (skimmed down for easier reading):

```
include '< const class id >.php';
class ParseFunctions {
    private $_id = '';

    public function __construct(){
        $id = new IDS;
        $this->_id = $id::<const class id>;
    }

    public function set_id(){
        $new_id = $this->id;  <---  this line throws the error
        $print_r($new_id);
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated!  thank you!

Comment: `$this->id` doesn't exist. Should it be `$this->_id`?

Comment: Unrelated to this problem, but that is a weird looking setter, as you aren't passing a parameter to it. Can you show how you are calling `set_id()`? If you are trying to call in static context somewhere, that would cause this error.

Comment: The id/_id thing shouldn't cause this error.

To be honest the nature of this error is such that unless we can see how set_id() is called it will be hard to help. 

My guess is you're calling set_id statically somewhere (eg ::set_id() and not ->set_id())

Comment: `$id::<const class id>;`Is this PHP ? oO

Comment: shouldn't it be `$new_id = $this->_id` ?

Comment: Post actual code, not excerpts and stylised identifier placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's because you are calling the `set_id` method statically** (along the lines of `ParseFunctions::set_id()`).

You can't use `$this` in that (static) context. You can only use `$this` within an instance (object context), i.e., `$obj = new ParseFunctions; $obj->set_id();` (no context error will be thrown when the pertinent line is reached)

Answer (score 0):

Though you haven't shown how you call `set_id()` in your code.  The likely error is that you are calling it in a static context somewhere like this:

```
ParseFunctions::set_id()
```

The is static context and would disallow use of `$this` within the called method since their is no concrete object that has been instantiated.

Comment: thank you for you're answer!  you pointed me in the right direction!